# how to connect expo app on my own phone to firebase?Is it possible?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm new to React native. Today I wanted to create a login and sign up page linked to firebase. I followed this tutorial  -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkuQAjnaSbM&t=110s - word for word and found it very successful.

I installed the expo application on my ios phone and I get the builds from there. The only difference between us and the tutorial in the video is that it uses an android emulator and I get build on the expo application on my real phone. But the problem is that I cannot add new users to the firebase via the script. I also share the code. I would appreciate if you help.

```
handleSignUp=() => {
    firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then(userCredentinals => {
            return userCredentinals.user.updateProfile({
                displayName: this.state.name
            });
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.messsage}));
};
```

somehow I can't connect with firebase. but I'm sure I put the config code block in the right place. Maybe I am not authorized to write my own phone to the database I use as an emulator?

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}> 
                        <Text style={{color:"#FFF", fontWeight: "500"}}
                        onPress={this.handleSignUp}
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
                        >Kayıt Ol</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the error message you are getting?

Comment: there is no error message.everythings look like okey. but when ı clicked signup button (relation handleSignUp) no action. no change anything. can be firebase settings is problem?

Comment: Firebase rules are affected on its `database`. According to my knowledge, `auth` is not affected by the Firebase rules. Are you sure you are actually calling the function correctly when you pressed the button? Please put a `console.log()` and see if the function is called correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your function like this.

```
const handleSignUp = () => {
    console.log('Function is called');

    firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then(userCredentinals => {
            console.log('Success');
            return userCredentinals.user.updateProfile({
                displayName: this.state.name
            });
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
       this.setState({ errorMessage: error.messsage});
    });
};
```

Then please update your question with what you get displayed in the `console`. Then I will be able to help you to solve this problem.

Comment: I updated as you said. I don't get any logs. First of all I want to ask. I am using Visual Studio. I have to look over there to read the logs (I added a photo to the question) right? there is no action. I am writing the code in the view component where I call the function. I'm making a mistake somewhere but I couldn't find it !.

Comment: seems your function is not called properly. If the function is called, it should at least print 'Success' on the console. Can you please update your question with the full code of the particular component? I want to see how you attempt to call the function.

Comment: UUUPPS ı understood!. The logs on localhost and I am using onpressed funct in text props.. false! must be in touchableOpacity component!! Thank u.

Comment: You are welcome! :-) Yeah, It should be like that. Go ahead and try it. Most probably you will be successful. Good luck!

Comment: In the second comment, it should be corrected as, ".... at lease print 'Function is called'..."